# Downloading Selenium & Only Getting nupkg Files & No dlls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dll

I downloaded Selenium WebDriver a couple weeks ago, created a C# project in VS and was having issues with xpaths not being recognised despite the xpath being validated in other tools. I expected it could be down to my install and i must have missed something out.

I decided to remove all Selenium packages and start again watching an install vid on Youtube, however every time i go to the Selenium website and download either the latest or previous versions i end up with nupkg files. These files dont work when adding them as references to the project in VS.

Why am i not getting the dll files in the download and how would i go about getting them?

As you may gather, i'm relatively new to working outside of an off-the-self automation tool that handles this type of configuration for you!

Thanks In Advance

Rob

Comment: when you look at your references, are there little yield signs on the selenium refs? If not, you can right click/view properties and see where the dll is located... visual studio pulls the nupkg and then unbundles it and references the dlls for you. its not always obvious but if you look at your references, it tells a story.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET bindings, when unzipped, yield .nupkg files inside the zip archives downloadable from the [official drop point](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html). However, .nupkg files are themselves only zip archives. You can either extract the individual assemblies using [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or just renaming the .nupkg to .zip; or alternatively, you can [create a local NuGet feed](https://codurance.com/2015/05/04/creating-a-local-nuget-repository/) and use them just like any other NuGet packages.